# Error: Cannot find module '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config' while testing my LWC from vs code

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, vs-code, lwc-jest

I have started my practice on LWC testing While i'm run this command:"npm run test:unit"

i am getting this error:Cannot find module '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config'.

Error body is:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/config'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\TEAMABSYZ-68\OneDrive\Documents\SimpleCalculator\jest.config.js
- C:\Users\TEAMABSYZ-68\OneDrive\Documents\SimpleCalculator\node_modules\jest-config\build\readConfigFileAndSetRootDir.js
- C:\Users\TEAMABSYZ-68\OneDrive\Documents\SimpleCalculator\node_modules\jest-config\build\index.js
- C:\Users\TEAMABSYZ-68\OneDrive\Documents\SimpleCalculator\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\cli\index.js  
- C:\Users\TEAMABSYZ-68\OneDrive\Documents\SimpleCalculator\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\bin\jest.js
- C:\Users\TEAMABSYZ-68\OneDrive\Documents\SimpleCalculator\node_modules\jest\bin\jest.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)      
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\TEAMABSYZ-68\OneDrive\Documents\SimpleCalculator\jest.config.js:1:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)  
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
```

Can anyone tell why this is giving error and when it will give these type of errors?

Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you may not have config file. Check [this](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest#overriding-jest-config) document.

> Add a jest.config.js file to the root of the Salesforce DX project as
>   described [here](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest#overriding-jest-config). You must add this file to run Jest from Visual Studio
>   Code.